# Access component parameters inside caller component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component which I call inside another component as:

COMPONENT 1

```
<template>
  <FiltersComponent />
</template>


export default Vue.extend({
 components: { FiltersComponent }

)}
```

So, this FiltersComponents have some parameters I want to access into my component one

COMPONENT 2 DATA

```
data() {
    return {
      TestList: [] as string[],
      Test2List: null as string[] | null,
    }
  },
```

How can I access that TestList and Test2List inside COMPONENT 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities: If one component is a child component or sibling of the other, you might want to take a loop at [`props`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#props-declaration) (passing data down) and [`events`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-handling) (passing data up). Otherwise, if they are not siblings or children, you can use a store like [`vuex`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

To use the docs example:

vue entry point: (e.g., `app.js`):

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

// Create a new store instance.
const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return {
      someProperty: 'someValue'
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    update (state, value) {
      state.someProperty = value
    }
  }
})

const app = createApp({ /* your root component */ })

// Install the store instance as a plugin
app.use(store)
```

In your component's `script`-section:

```
  this.$store.commit('update', 'YOUR_VALUE')
```

Other component:

```
  const val = this.$store.state.someProperty
```

However, this is only a very basic example. You should definitely check out the docs, especially the sections about [state](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components), [getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) and [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html).

Comment: Can you give an example of how can I achieve this via vuex?

Answer (score 0):

Always store the state as high in the component tree as you need, meaning that if you need these lists inside component 1, store them there. Then, you can use props and events to access and update the data inside component 2.

Alternatively, you can use a centralized store like Vuex.

Comment: Can you give an example of how can I achieve this via vuex?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using `ref`,

Check the below example

```
<template>
  <FiltersComponent ref="childComponent" /> <!-- Adding ref over here -->
</template>


export default Vue.extend({
 components: { FiltersComponent }

)}
```

then in any of your methods or mounted section in Component 1. You can access Component2 data like

```
this.$refs.childComponent.TestList
```

or

```
this.$refs.childComponent.Test2List
```

So simple isn't it? ;)

Comment: I try to use the `ref="childComponent"` but it is throwing "No overload matches this call"

Comment: are you using typescript or javaascript?

Comment: Also is it vue2 or vue3?

Comment: typescript and it is vue2

Comment: could you p.ease attach the complete code of that component in the question?